# Maximal subgroups which are not open in pro-2 groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is it true that a pro-2 group $G$ with $G/\Phi(G)\cong C_2\times C_2$ may have a maximal subgroup which is not open?

Motivation: The Frattini subgroup of a profinite group by definition, is the intersection of all maximal proper open subgroups of the group. So I am asking of existence of maximal subgroups (between all subgroups) which are not open. Some of  properties of such maximal subgroups are mentioned below in the comments:

1) They are not normal.

2) They are not closed. They are dense in the group.

Comment: If $H$ is a closed subgroup then it's the intersection of $HN$ when $N$ ranges open normal subgroups of $G$; in particular if $H$ is maximal and closed then it's open. So you're asking about dense subgroups, right?

Comment: I think you are right. But I thought to find a non-normal maximal subgroup.

Comment: I was speaking of subgroups, not necessarily normal subgroups.

Comment: What I ask is equivalent to find a non- normal maximal subgroup

Comment: I was asking for clarification: you're asking about subgroups that are not necessarily closed?

Comment: Yes. Non-open maximal subgroups are not closed and their closure is equal to the whole of the group. I mention above some words about the motivation

Comment: Just for completeness, that they are not normal follows from the observation that a maximal subgroup that is normal is the kernel of a homomorphism onto a cyclic group of prime order, combined with Serre's result that in a top. f.g. pro-$p$-group every finite index subgroup is open.

Comment: I don't know either if there are such subgroups when "maximal" is replaced with "with finite corank" (in the sense that $G$ is generated by the subgroup plus finitely many elements).